# my UI thread was not sleeping properly

Tags: android, multithreading, view

i'm making a 15 puzzle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle) game, and i have an activity for user to select the background image, and then i pass that image to a new activity in order to scale and crop it.

Now i want to show the solution to the user first for 3 secs then it would shuffle, i'm using code like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //...skip the code that gets the image and scales it 

    start();
}
```

then in my start() funcion:

```
public void start() {

    //the createPuzzle function would create all the Views(tiles)
    //and add them to the root LinearLayout using addView() function
    createPuzzle(game.getBoardConfig(), dimension);

    //i was trying to sleep here

    shuffle();
}
```

i used:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

or:

```
SystemClock.sleep(3000);
```

but neither of them worked properly, they all paused the the thread right after i selected the image and when it was paused i can't see the new activity and the tiles i created. When the thread resumes, it was already showing the shuffled puzzle.

I've been looking at the documentation for quite a while but still can't figure out what's wrong with my code, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't make the UI thread sleep because that will lock up the entire UI thread which is a no-no. Instead, use a Handler to post a runnable with a delay...like

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              shuffle(); 
         } 
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you so much!! I tried to use a Timer before to schedule the shuffle as well, but that doesn't work. i think i should get a better understanding on these objects. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @QQending, you're very welcome. Check out my blogpost for an explanation of some of the internals: http://levinotik.com/2012/01/loopers-handlers-runtimeexceptions-explained/