# Problems with sleep() in combination with a network task on Android

Tags: java, android, sleep

I need to implement a download task which emits a string which I show in a textview. This works perfectly with this [method](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Because of data protection the text in the view shall be deleted after ca. 10 seconds and thats where my problems start.

This is my onPostExecute()-method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  txtOutput.setText(result);
  int i = 0;
  while (txtOutput.getText().toString().equals("") && i <= 30) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    i++;
  }
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
  txtOutput.setText("");
}
```

The while-loop is there, so the 10 seconds don't start until the output is shown.

My problem is that the output never is shown.

/edit: I adjusted the String comparison

Comment: Do you have some logs ? Or just nothing ?

Comment: Do not use `==` but `equals()` or `isEmpty()`

Comment: Can you, please, explain this: "until the output is shown"? When you call setText() , TextView will be redrawn "immediately". 
And do not sleep your UI thread! onPostExecute executes in your UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare string you need to use the `equals()` method not `==`. You can also use `isEmpty()` So try

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    txtOutput.setText(result);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            txtOutput.setText("");
        }
    }, 10000);        
}
```

Also do not sleep the Ui Thread (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122853/my-ui-thread-was-not-sleeping-properly))

Comment: Ok, that was just a careless mistake and not the main problem. The loop was an idea I had, when it didn't work without it.

Comment: Remove the loop. See the edit with Handler (will not block UI Thread)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the `while` loop; I tried the following code and am getting the result perfectly.

```
System.out.println("1");
int i = 0;
while (i <= 30) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    i++;
}
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
System.out.println("2");
```

I am getting:

```
1
```

and after 40sec:

```
2
```

Comment: Well, my problem lies in the combination of a network task and the loop. Alone, they both work, but not together...

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        txtOutput.setText(result);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e) { }
        txtOutput.setText("");
    }
```

try this code.

Comment: @rohit: that was the first thing I've been trying out :(

Comment: Guys sleeping UI thread is bad idea\ !! Post with handler and it will work.